# Replacing the first word in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace the first word in a column (pandas DF) with "MS". I have read multiple sources online and cannot find what I am looking for.

As the first word can vary throughout I was thinking of using a positional argument rather than the regular one below:

```
df['columnName'].replace(['old value'],'new value')
```

I have a snippet code to isolate the first word in the column but I'm not sure how to go about implementing the .replace method

```
df['hardware']= df['hardware'].str.split(' ').str[0]
```

**Sample df**

| Hardware |
| --- |
| Micro Software |
| sample Software |
| MS Screen |
| Xyx Screen |

**Desired output**

| Hardware |
| --- |
| MS Software |
| MS Software |
| MS Screen |
| MS Screen |

Many thanks!

Comment: Please share sample inputs data & what's expected output.

Comment: @IbraheemAyoup SHARED :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex replacement:

```py
df['columnName'] = df['columnName'].str.replace(r'^\w+', 'MS')
```

The regex pattern `^\w+` will match the first word in the column.

Comment: very helpful thanks, I wasn't aware that this could be achieved through regex. I had never seen the ^\w+ pattern

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about df.iloc method?

```
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('hardware')] = 'new value'
```

Comment: I did consider the Iloc method but I wasn't sure how to structure the code, thanks